# mat-datepicker displayed wrong on angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material2

For some reason, the material date picker doesn't display well. I am new to angular material 2 date picker and maybe I have somewhere a mistake.

The strange is I don t have any error in the chrome console.

Because for the first time I play with date picker , maybe I missing something, please some expert guides me. add list show me a simple example how o set up a date picker.

[image]

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.11",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

### This is my code.

#### material.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule ],
  exports: [ MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import 'hammerjs';

import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### test.component.html

```
<div>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

#### test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params  } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenav, PageEvent, MatIconRegistry, MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl  } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-analytics-timeframes',
  templateUrl: './analytics-timeframes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analytics-timeframes.component.css']
})
export class AnalyticsTimeframesComponent implements OnInit {


 constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {}


}
```

Comment: might be that you have unclosed tags check for </div> closures

Comment: No, I have double check all divs are clossed

Comment: this most likely has to do with your styles, mainly your theme import. can you post that code?

Comment: Yes, I fix this. I have admin.scss styles that style the table.OMG sow hard to find the solution.Thank you all.